# Help in proof involving matrices

Tags: matrices

> Let  $$ P=\begin{pmatrix}11&-6\\18&-10\end{pmatrix}. $$ Show that
>   there is no $2\times2$ matrix $Q$ such that $Q^2=P$.

I don't know how to approach this question. **Is brute force the only way to go?** That is, take a general matrix 
$$
Q=\begin{pmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{pmatrix}
$$
and get 
$$
Q^2=\begin{pmatrix}a^2+bc&b(a+d)\\c(a+c)&bc+d^2\end{pmatrix}.
$$
Then equate element by element and try to find a contradiction? This seems tedious and not very instructive.

In a previous part of the question, we established that $P^2+P=2I$, $|P|=-2$, and $$P^{-1}=\frac12\begin{pmatrix}10&-6\\18&-11\end{pmatrix}.$$
But I don't see how these would be useful...

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: is Q restricted to contain integers only?

Comment: @EmmadKareem: Not according to my understanding. The question doesn't say $a,b,c,d$ have to be integers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

prove that no real Matrix $Q$ exists using determinants ...

$|P|=-2$ so if $Q^2 = P$ then $|Q|$ would need to be imaginary since $|Q^2|=|Q|^2=-2$

Answer (score 2):

The Eigen values of $P$ are $2$ and $-1$. Now there exists a Matrix $Q$ such that $Q^2=P$. So $Det(Q^2)=Det(P)$ $\implies$ $Det(Q)=i\sqrt{2}$ or $-i\sqrt{2}$.

Now by Cayley hamilton theorem the characteristic equation of $Q$ is of the form

$$Q^2-Tr(Q)Q+Det(Q)I=0$$ $\implies$ Since $Q^2=P$

$$Tr(Q)Q= P+Det(Q)I=\begin{pmatrix}
11+i\sqrt{2} & -6\\ 
18 & -10+i\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Taking Determinant on both sides we get

$$Det(Tr(Q)Q)=-4+i\sqrt{2}$$ Using $Det(kA)=k^nDet(A)$ we get

$$Tr(Q)^2Det(Q)=-4+i\sqrt{2}$$ So

$$Tr(Q)^2=\frac{-4+i\sqrt{2}}{i\sqrt{2}}=1+2i\sqrt{2}$$ So

$$Tr(Q)=\sqrt{1+2i\sqrt{2}}=\sqrt{2}+i$$  Finally

$$Q=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}+i}\begin{pmatrix}
11+i\sqrt{2} & -6\\ 
18 & -10+i\sqrt{2}
\end{pmatrix}$$

$$Q=\begin{pmatrix}
 4\sqrt{2}-3i& -2\sqrt{2}+2i\\ 
6\sqrt{2}-6i & -3\sqrt{2}+4i
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. This is more than I need, but I now learn something more.